# Bootstrap scss override deletes $theme-colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, overriding

I added the last version of bootstrap to my npm project and created an stylesheet with the code below. So I import the functions and the variables, then I want to override the `primary` `theme-colors` variable and then import the rest of the bootstrap, as is told in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/). The problem is that when I run this code, only the primary button has it's required color, the other colors are removed. If I comment the code, all colors work as expected. Does anyone know what is going on?

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #D4AF37
);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: How did you find out other colors are removed... May I know what html u used to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Minutes after posting this question I found it myself. The docs article I linked is for 4.0, [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/webpack/) article is for 5.0. This will work:

```
$primary: #D4AF37;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```